# Campos com mesmo nome em diferentes tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, tabela-banco-de-dados, normalização

Campos com o mesmo nome em tabelas diferentes podem causar conflito na hora de `normalizar` ou fazer algum `inner join`?

## Exemplos

#### Tabela Fornecedor

1. **Campo:** nome
2. **Campo:** sobrenome
3. **Campo:** email

#### Tabela Produto

1. **Campo:** nome
2. **Campo:** data_de_entrega
3. **Campo:** Quantidade

Esse é um exemplo bem simples com apenas 2 tabelas, mas se eu possuo em torno de 50 tabelas ou mais, dentro de um determinado projeto, qual a solução eficaz? Já li sobre alguns tópicos dizendo para colocar `nome_da_tabela_nome_do_campo`, isso é uma forma de escapar?

De acordo com [*style guides* do SQL](https://www.sqlstyle.guide/pt-br/).

> **Tabelas**
>
> Utilize um nome coletivo ou menos idealmente, plurais. Por
>   exemplo, (em ordem de preferência) pessoal e empregados.
>
> Não utilize
>   prefixos com tbl ou qualquer outro prefixo descritivo ou notação
>   húngara.
>
> Nunca dê a uma tabela o mesmo nome de uma das suas colunas e
>   vice versa.
>
> **> Evite quando possível concatenar dois nomes de tabelas
>   para criar o nome de uma tabela de relacionamento.**
>
> No lugar de
>   mecanicos_de_carro, prefira servicos.

> **Colunas**
>
> Sempre utilize nomes no singular.
>
> Quando possível, evite usar apenas id como identificador primário da
>   tabela.
>
> Não adicione uma
>   coluna como o mesmo nome da tabela e vice versa.
>
> Sempre utilize caixa
>   baixa, exceto onde capitalização fizer sentido (como em nomes
>   próprios).

Então a parte que diz:

> Evite quando possível concatenar dois nomes de tabelas para criar o
>   nome de uma tabela de relacionamento.

Valeria a mesma coisa para os campos?

Comment: Sim pode causar conflito, mas é facilmente solucionável, basta você prefixar o nome do campo com o nome da tabela. Não vejo como isso pode ter qualquer impacto no processo de normalização.

Comment: tipo, seguindo o exemplo que foi dado: a `tabela Fornecedor` ficaria: `fornecedor_nome, fornecedor_sobrenome, fornecedor_email`, e a `tabela Produto`: `produto_nome, produto_data_de_entrega, produto_quantidade` desse jeito?

Comment: Não, eu quis dizer nome_da_tabela.nome_do_campo, toda a vez que houver alguma tipo de conflito com os nomes dos campos das tabelas envolvidas no comando. Não é na definição da tabela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não pode causar conflito, se fizer tudo certo, que é o que todo mundo faz, certo? Na hora de usar os nomes em uma *query* deve ter uma qualificação completa, ou seja, o nome da coluna e o nome da tabela (geralmente este nome é usado com um alias, então `produto` provavelmente será usado como `p`), então seu nome será `p.nome`, que será diferente de `f.nome`. Se não gostar da abreviação use o sobrenome completo (`produto.nome` e `fornecedor.nome`), isto é suficiente para desambiguar os nomes e evitar conflitos.

Colocar o nome da tabela no nome da coluna, de forma geral, é algo redundante e desnecessário. Existe apenas alguns casos em que o nome é descritivo. Por exemplo se você tem uma chave estrangeira em uma coluna, então você não vai usar só o nome dela, usará um qualificado, então se a chave estrangeira é o `id` de um fornecedor, o nome desta colina será `fornecedor_id`. Aí tem gente que acha que neste caso o `id` na tabela `fornecedor` também será ser completamente qualificado, mesmo sendo redundante, para que todas as colunas que representam a mesma coisa sejam iguais, mas há muita gente que discorda disto.

Dê nomes simples e semânticos para as colunas, evite redundâncias e complicações, por isso não coloque informação desnecessária, por isso os nomes que usou são adequados. Alguns dirão que `data_da_ entrega` já tem redundância, `entrega` é uma data, não precisa dizer, mas de fato há quem não concorde com isso.

A pergunta cita um tal de *style guide* do SQL, parecem boas recomendações gerais (não regras pra seguir cegamente), mas tem alguns pontos ruins. Aquilo é o trabalho de alguém que deve ser respeitado, mas não é alguém que tem autoridade sobre o assunto, foi algo que achou na internet, não quer dizer que tudo ali esteja correto ou que seja unanimidade, de fato olhando todos os elementos eu discordo de vários e alguns parecem bem errados, independente do meu gosto.

> Nunca dê a uma tabela o mesmo nome de uma das suas colunas e vice-versa.

Isso é bom, mas não é uma verdade absoluta.

> Sempre utilize nomes no singular

Geralmente sim, mas tem casos que isso não deve ser feito.

> Sempre utilize caixa baixa, exceto onde capitalização fizer sentido (como em nomes próprios)

Bobagem. É só gosto da pessoa.

> Evite quando possível concatenar dois nomes de tabelas para criar o nome de uma tabela de relacionamento.

Evitar sim, nunca fazer não.

> Valeria a mesma coisa para os campos?

De forma geral, sim, só não tome como regra fixa, conforme citado acima.

O que você chama de campo na verdade se chama coluna, campo é uma informalidade que as pessoas entendem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A pergunta que farei agora foge um pouco do escopo da pergunta principal citada anteriormente, mas em questões a tabelas " [...] mas se eu possuo em torno de 50 tabelas ou mais [...]", o exemplo  `Tabela Curso` e `Tabela Evento` e ambos possuem uma outra tabela chamada `Categoria`, mas como não podemos colocar o nome de duas tabelas iguais, então deveríamos chamar a  segunda Tabela de `Categoria` como`Categoria_Curso` / `Categoria_Evento` (quebrando ela em duas), ou unificar essa unica tabela como `Categoria` e fazer um relacionamento entre as 3 tabelas?

Comment: Então faça uma nova pergunta, mas pense bem se ela está coerente, do jeito que fez não faz muito sentido. De qualquer forma, eu já disse que isso não é uma verdade absoluta, depende do que está fazendo.

Comment: Chamar campo à coluna é algo que sei que não é correcto mas que invariavelmente me esqueço.

Answer (score 1):

Não, porque ao nome da coluna pode ser acrescentado o nome da tabela para a distinguir.

Ao nomear uma coluna a preocupação deve ser identificá-la/descrever seu conteúdo da melhor forma possível.

Nomes como **fornecedor_nome** e **produto_nome** não são necessários e devem ser evitados.

Quando for necessário identificar/distiguir uma coluna use **fornecedor.nome** e **produto.nome**

A excepção poderá ser em campos que representam chaves estrangeiras, quando não houver melhor forma de os distinguir.